# Apache - serving pre-compressed gzip file doesn't work

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble using the rewrite rules for Apache (2.4) to serve compressed files.

My javascript bundling process generate .gz files for every .js it creates. I've activated the rewrite module on apache `a2enmod rewrite` and set the `.htacess` file like this:

```
AddEncoding gzip .gz
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
RewriteRule "^(.*)\.js" "$1\.js\.gz" [QSA]

# Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
RewriteRule "\.js\.gz$" "-" [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

<FilesMatch ".+\.(js\.gz)$">
  Header append Content-Encoding gzip
  Header append worked yes   
</FilesMatch>
```

The problems I'm running are:

1. The first condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip` never evaluates to true. On Chrome Developer tools the client is sending this header `Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br` (I've tried adding gzip, deflate, br to the condition but it doesn't work);
2. Even if I take this above condition out I can't see the header `Content-Encoding` in Chrome dev-tools;
3. I don't see `Content-length` in response headers. But it responds with a `Transfer-Encoding:chunked` which I find weird;

These are the modules that are enabled on my apache (I think they are enabled by default in my ubuntu dist because I didn't active any of those)

```
access_compat.load  authz_user.load  filter.load       rewrite.load
alias.conf          autoindex.conf   headers.load      setenvif.conf
alias.load          autoindex.load   mime.conf         setenvif.load
auth_basic.load     deflate.conf     mime.load         status.conf
authn_core.load     deflate.load     mpm_event.conf    status.load
authn_file.load     dir.conf         mpm_event.load
authz_core.load     dir.load         negotiation.conf
authz_host.load     env.load         negotiation.load
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have there looks correct and seems to work fine on my computer, which suggests the problem is elsewhere.  Some possibilities I can think of:

- Perhaps a cache server/reverse proxy is messing with things (that would be my first guess, unless you're testing on localhost or set up everything yourself or otherwise know there isn't such a server)
- Or perhaps mod_deflate is interfering anyways (I don't seem to have it installed on my computer so I can't test it); if you have access to the main server configuration maybe try commenting out the `LoadModule` line for it?
- If any subdirectory has a `.htaccess` file that also uses rewrite rules, then rewrite rules in the parent directory won't run.  (If this is the issue, `RewriteOptions Inherit` should work with these specific rules.  However, this wouldn't explain the chunked encoding.)
- Force refresh or clear cache in your browser?

Comment: Thank you so much. In the end we figured that we had datapower running (an IBM proxy) which was stripping the Accept-encoding header.